# cannot serialize

Tags: java, exception, serialization, nullpointerexception, frame

i'm doing a simple dice game in java with swing components. i just want to save the progress of the game, so i have  created a class called `State` and then i want to serialize it. 
but when i try to do it, a `NullPointerException` returned:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(SynthLookAndFeel.java:364)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(SynthLookAndFeel.java:328)
    at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthViewportUI.update(SynthViewportUI.java:168)
...
```

with debugger i saw that the file is created, so the object has been serialized, but i cant continue executing the main program.

i have this method in the class State:

```
public void SaveState() {
    try {
        ObjectOutput out = new ObjectOutputStream(new 
        FileOutputStream("C://game.ser"));
        out.writeObject(this);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
```

and the class implements `Serializable`

Comment: You are getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`. Is that the complete stacktrace.

Comment: Well, silently ignoring exceptions is usually a bad idea.  But I don't see any way that the content of your `SaveState()` method would be likely to cause the later exception.  After you call the method, are you setting some reference to `null`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your object serialization. The full stack trace will tell you where that exception is coming from.

Comment: Your class implements Serializable, but does every member type within that class also implement Serializable (and recursively for those)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! the problem was that i was trying to serialize a DefaultDataModel, a datamember of State, so i will search another way to save the JTable with the scores! thanks for the answers!

Comment: Congrats on the fix. When you are able, please mark your answer as accepted so that others can learn from your solution. Cheers~